Video component keeps fetching the cdn file without any trigger
I am using Expo-AV and react-native-video to display videos in my app
import React from 'react'
//import Video, { VideoRef } from 'react-native-video';
import { Video } from "expo-av";

export default function test_video() {
    const videoRef = React.useRef();
    return (
        <Video
            source={{ uri: URL_ + '/hls_media/1709272706_11983_7564/video.m3u8' }}
            muted={true}
            ref={videoRef}
            shouldPlay={false}
        />
    )
}

I am noticing a strange behaviour, the video component keeps sending requests to the cdn as shown in the image - it keeps fetching the m3u8 file every few seconds

I know that updating states will cause the video component to re-render and resend the request to the cdn - but this happen without any state update or any action or even playing the video
The content for m3u8 file is:
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:3.000000,
video0.ts
#EXTINF:3.000000,
video1.ts
#EXTINF:2.366667,
video2.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST


What are the contents of that file?

@tobiv i have edited the question and added the content of the file
